# how to rename table_name in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

how to rename the table_name in sqlite3 database. It shows error on every attempt on renaming the table_name.

sqlite> rename table user to User;
Error: near "rename": syntax error

sqlite> alter table user rename to User;
Error: there is already another table or index with this name: User

sqlite> rename user to User;
Error: near "rename": syntax error

sqlite> RENAME user to User;
Error: near "RENAME": syntax error

sqlite> alter user rename to User;
Error: near "user": syntax error
sqlite>

sqlite> ALTER user RENAME to User;
Error: near "user": syntax error

sqlite> alter table user rename to User;
Error: there is already another table or index with this name: User

sqlite> sp_rename user to User;
Error: near "sp_rename": syntax error

sqlite> sp_rename 'user' to 'User';
Error: near "sp_rename": syntax error

sqlite> sp_rename 'user','User';
Error: near "sp_rename": syntax error

sqlite> rename table user to User;
Error: near "rename": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

`user` is a reserved word. Escape it with backticks and better use a different name

```
ALTER TABLE `user` RENAME TO users;
```

Comment: worked. thankyou

Comment: Using double quotes is ANSI standard SQL and the recommended way to escape names. Sqlite just supports backticks as a half-hearted attempt at MySQL compatibility (And same with square brackets and MS SQL).